# CKEditor: is Submenu supported in plugin?

Tags: ckeditor

Is it possible to have a submenu in ckeditor plugin? i.e

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Submenus (menu groups) are supported. There's an [example](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/tabletools/plugin.js#L807-L961) of how they can be defined. Provided you have the `tabletools` plugin loaded in your editor, you can observe it if you right-click somethe table cell.

[image]

Comment: its so complex example and its difficult to understand:( kindly give relatively simple example (if you have) or direct to some suitable tutorial.

Comment: @Rabeel At the moment there's no tutorial but reading code to learn the CKEditor menu system.

Comment: I have tried that code and come up with a symbol of drop down but its content are not appearing. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197948/ckeditor-submenu-drop-downlist-not-appearing)

Answer (score 1):

This snippet must add a parent menu item and get sub menu items from server and add those under the parent menu.

```js
var myMenu{
    openEditor: function(sender) {
        sender.ckeditor(function(element) {
        }, {
            on: {
                instanceReady: function(c) {
                    myMenu.setupParameterMenu(c.editor);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    setupParameterMenu: function(ceditor) {
        ceditor.addMenuGroup('Parameters');

        var subItems = {};

        var parentMenu = {};

        parentMenu.label = "Dynamic Parameters";
        parentMenu.group = 'Parameters';
        parentMenu.order = 1;
        parentMenu.getItems = function() {
            return subItems;
        };

        ceditor.addMenuItem("Dynamic Parameters", parentMenu);

        ceditor.contextMenu.addListener(function(element, selection) {
            return {"Dynamic Parameters": CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF};
        });

        $.getJSON("/JSON/Parameters", function(json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                var subMenu = myMenu.subMenuItem(json[i], ceditor);

                for (var key in subMenu) {
                    subItems[key] = subMenu[key];
                }
            }
        });
    },
    subMenuItem: function(param, ceditor) {
        ceditor.addCommand(param, {
            exec: function(editor)
            {
                var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml('<span contenteditable="false">' + param + '</span>');
                editor.insertElement(element);
            }
        });

        var zet = {};

        zet.label = param;
        zet.command = param;
        zet.group = 'Parameters';
        zet.order = i + 1;

        ceditor.addMenuItem("" + param, zet);

        var n = {};

        n[param] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF;

        return n;
    }
  }
```