# CKEditor: Submenu (drop downlist) not appearing

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, ckeditor, submenu

I need a drop down submenu list within the drop down menu list in plugin. but problem is, that menu shows that It has drop down submenu list but contents of list are not being loaded. empty submenu is shown.

Snap shot:

[image]

code :

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'microdata',
{
   requires : [ 'styles', 'button' ],
   init : function( editor )
    {
        var  markup= editor.config.languages,
                items = {};
        for ( var i = 0 ; i < markup.length ; i++ )
        {
            var parts = markup[i].split( '=' );
            var name= parts[1].split('org/');
            items[ parts[ 0 ] ] =
                {
                    label : parts[ 0 ],
                    group : 'microdata',
                    icon: this.path + 'icon1.png' ,
                    order : i,
                    getItems: function()
                        {
                            var selection = editor.getSelection();
                            return {
                                name: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
                                friend: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF
                            };
                        }

        };
             var  name=
                {
                  label: 'name',
                  group: 'microdata',
                  //command: 'nameCmd',
                  order: 5
                }
        editor.addMenuGroup( 'microdata' );
        editor.addMenuItems( items,name);/*,
                friend:
                {
                  label: 'friend',
                  group: 'microdata',
                  //command: 'friendCmd',
                  order: 10
                }
                );*/
        editor.ui.add( 'Microdata', CKEDITOR.UI_MENUBUTTON,
        {
            label: 'Microdata',
            command: 'Microdata',
            modes : { wysiwyg:1 },
            className : 'cke_button_microdata',
            icon: this.path + 'icon1.png' ,
                    onMenu : function()
                {
                    var activeItems = {};

                    for ( var prop in items )
                    {
                        if ( items.hasOwnProperty( prop ) )
                            activeItems[ prop ] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON;
                    }

                    return  activeItems;
                }
        } );
      }
} );
CKEDITOR.config.languages = [ 'Place=http://schema.org/Place'];
```

Commands are not added yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: contents of inner drop down list are not showing up?

Comment: The problem with your code is that your for loop is being escaped early by your return call. Provide more code and If you would like anyone to be able to render you an example.

Comment: That is the whole code for plugin. Then what could be the solution??